# ExtJS grid 'reset'

Tags: extjs4

I'm on ExtJS 4 and using an MVC approach.  I've created a simple grid view class, and have added a componentquery type 'ref' to that view in my controller.  Within the initial grid view itself I set several columns to be hidden and some to be visible by default.  The rendering of the grid with those settings is all working fine.

Then I have a button that, when clicked and based on some other conditions, will make some of the initially hidden grid columns visible.  This works as well.

But what I need is a way to later 'reset' the grid to its initial view (with the correct columns hidden/visible, as they were initially).

I've tried various permutations of the following with no effect:

```
var theGrid = this.getTheGrid();
theGrid.reconfigure(store, theGrid.initialConfig.columns);
theGrid.getView().refresh();
```

I suppose I could loop through every column and reset its 'hidden' state, but would think there's a way to just 'reset' back to what's set in the class?  Advice?

**SOLUTION UPDATE**

Appreciate the pointer from tuespetre.  For anyone coming along in the future looking for specifics, here is what was needed (at least for my implementation):

- Within the view, moved the column defs into a variable
- Within the view, columns ref within the class becomes:

  ```
  columns: myColumns,
  ```
- Within the view, the following function created within the class:

  ```
  resetGrid: function(){
      this.reconfigure(null, myColumns);
  },
  ```
- Within the controller:

  ```
  var theGrid = this.getTheGrid();
  theGrid.resetGrid();
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just need to create a function on your view class to encapsulate that functionality.